# Trying to trigger scroll event by using jquery.mousewheel

Tags: javascript, triggers, scroll, mousewheel

I'm having some trouble with triggering a scroll event by using jquery.mousewheel. I want to "expand" the scroll event for #bio-content-container to trigger when scrolling over #bio-slider-container.
I'm using following code:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;      
$("#bio-content-container").scroll(function () {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (st > lastScrollTop){
        scroll('Down');
    } else {
        scroll('Up');
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
});

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#bio-slider-container')
        .bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
            $("#bio-content-container").trigger('scroll');
            return false;
    });
});
```

I don't want to trigger scroll on #bio-slider-container, so that's why I'm using mousewheel. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to scroll the contents of #bio-content-container when you use the mousewheel over #bio-slider-container.  You might want to check out the [jquery.scrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin.  This code works for me (without seeing your HTML):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#bio-slider-container').bind('mousewheel', function (event, delta) {
        var content = $("#bio-content-container");
        if (delta < 0) {
            content.scrollTo("+=10");
        } else {
            content.scrollTo("-=10");
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually using scrollTo in a function to do some other thing, but i didn't think of this one. Anyway, is there a way to trigger a scroll event (e.g by clicking on a button..)?

Comment: Sure,

            `$('#btnScrollDown').on('click', function () {
                $("#bio-content-container").scrollTo("+=10");
            });`

Comment: That's not exactly what I have in mind. I need to trigger default .scroll() event, not .scrollTo(). 

I'm using .scroll() on #bio-content-container with nice easing. .scrollTo() doesn't look so nice even with easing. With use of scrollTo("+=10") it looks a bit laggy.